# Escaping question mark character in sed bash script variable

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a set of saved html files with links in them of the form http://mywebsite.com/showfile.cgi?key=somenumber but I want to kill the question mark (side-story is that firefox hates ? and randomly converts it to %3F I'm sure there's some magic fix but that's for another question...)

However, I think my code is causing the question-mark character to not be read/saved/handled properly when storing the options as a variable by bash

```
# Doesn't work (no pattern matched)
SED_OPTIONS='-i s/\.cgi\?key/\.cgikey/g'

# Works e.g. http://mywebsite.com/showfileblah?key=somenumber
SED_OPTIONS='-i s/\.cgi/blah/g'

# Leaves question mark in e.g. http://mywebsite.com/showfile.blah?key=somenumber
SED_OPTIONS='-i s/cgi\?/blah/g'

# Actual sed command run when using SED_OPTIONS (I define FILES earlier in
# the code)
sed $SED_OPTIONS $FILES

# Not using the SED_OPTIONS variable works
# e.g. http://mywebsite.com/showfile.cgikey=somenumber
sed -i s/\.cgi\?key/\.cgikey/g $FILES
```

How can I get the full command to work using the SED_OPTIONS variable?

Comment: `-i s/cgi\?/blah/g` should actually give you `http://mywebsite.com/showfile.blahkey=somenumber`.

Comment: I know! If I define it with SED_OPTIONS='-i s/cgi\?/blah/g' it leaves the question mark in, but if I write the options inline in the same line as I call the sed command "sed -i s/cgi\?/blah/g $FILES" it removes the question mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **safest way to store a list of options and arguments in variables is to use an *array***:

Also:

- You're using a *basic* regular expression (no `-r` or `-E` option), so `?` is not a special char. and needs no escaping.
- In the *replacement string*, which is not a regex, do not escape `.`.
- No need for option `g`, since you're only replacing *1* occurrence per line.

```sh
# Create array with individual options/arguments.
SED_ARGS=( '-i' 's/\.cgi?key/.cgikey/' )

# Invoke `sed` with array - note the double-quoting.
sed "${SED_ARGS[@]}" $FILES
```

Similarly, it would be safer to use an array for the list of input files. `$FILES` will only work if the individual filenames contain no embedded whitespace or other elements subject to shell expansions.

Generally:

- *Single*-quote string *literals*, such as the `sed` script here - to prevent the shell from interpreting them.
- *Double*-quote *variable references*, to prevent the shell from performing additional operations on them, such as pathname expansion (globbing) and word splitting (splitting into multiple tokens by whitespace).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest storing the arguments for `sed` in an array:

```
SED_OPTIONS=( '-i' '-e' 's/\.cgi?key/\.cgikey/g' )

sed "${SED_OPTIONS[@]}" $FILES
```

However, that's only a part of the trouble.

First, note that when you type:

```
sed -i s/\.cgi\?key/\.cgikey/g $FILES
```

what `sed` sees as the script argument is actually:

```
s/.cgi?key/.cgikey/g
```

because you didn't use any quotes to preserve the backslashes.  (To demonstrate, use `printf "%s\n" s/\.cgi\?key/\.cgikey/g`, thus avoiding any questions of whether `echo` is interpreting the backslashes.)  One side effect of this is that a URL such as:

```
http://example.com/nodotcgi?key=value
```

will be mapped to:

```
http://example.com/nodo.cgikey=value
```

Using the single quotes when setting SED_OPTIONS ensures that the backslashes are preserved where required, and not putting a backslash before the `?` works.  I have both GNU `sed` and BSD `sed` on my Mac; I've aliased them as `gnu-sed` and `bsd-sed` for clarity.  Note that BSD `sed` requires a suffix for `-i` and won't accept standard input with `-i`.  So, I've dropped the `-i` from the commands.

```
$ URLS=(http://example.com/script.cgi?key=value http://example.com/nodotcgi?key=value)
$ SED_OPTIONS=( '-e' 's/\.cgi?key/\.cgikey/g' )
$ printf "%s\n" "${URLS[@]}" | bsd-sed "${SED_OPTIONS[@]}"
http://example.com/script.cgikey=value
http://example.com/nodotcgi?key=value
$ printf "%s\n" "${URLS[@]}" | gnu-sed "${SED_OPTIONS[@]}"
http://example.com/script.cgikey=value
http://example.com/nodotcgi?key=value
$ SED_OPTIONS=( '-e' 's/\.cgi\?key/\.cgikey/g' )
$ printf "%s\n" "${URLS[@]}" | bsd-sed "${SED_OPTIONS[@]}"
http://example.com/script.cgikey=value
http://example.com/nodotcgi?key=value
$ printf "%s\n" "${URLS[@]}" | gnu-sed "${SED_OPTIONS[@]}"
http://example.com/script.cgi?key=value
http://example.com/nodotcgi?key=value
$
```

Note the difference in behaviour between the two versions of `sed` when there's a backslash before the question mark (second part of the example).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer - If you have $ SED_OPTIONS=( '-e' 's/\.cgi?key/\.cgikey/g' ) won't the question mark in the regex be interpreted as "you need zero or one of 'i'" and not as the actual symbol for a question mark?

Comment: As you can see, the answer is 'No' (`?` is not interpreted as one-or-more of `i`).  In standard (classic) `sed` regexes, `?` is not a metacharacter.  If you use extended regular expressions or similar, then you run into a different set of problems, but basic `sed` should/does use basic regular expressions where `?` is not a metacharacter.

Comment: Do you know what effect the \ before the dot in the replacement string does, as it's not a regex as noted by @mklement0 but when I try the replacement string with/without it I can't see any difference in behaviour?

Comment: I think it means that the next character is interpreted as itself rather than as a metacharacter, but the number of metacharacters in the replacement string is strictly limited (there's backslash itself, and `\n` for newline in `sed`, and then `\1` etc for replacing captures, and that's close to it).  So, both `\.` and `.` replace as `.`.

Comment: Perhaps that's what you meant, but to be explicit: While `\n` (and other control-char. escapes) in the replacement string  do work in _GNU_ `sed`, that is a non-POSIX extension, and doesn't work in FreeBSD `sed`. While `\.` happens to work, it's generally better not to quote chars. that don't need it, because such behavior is not regulated by POSIX, and different `sed` versions may behave differently: "The meaning of a ’\’ immediately followed by any character other than ’&’ , ’\’ , a digit, or the delimiter character used for this command, is unspecified." - http://man.cx/sed

Comment: @mklement0: Disentangling GNU extensions is often a painful process. The POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) description contains, after the statement you quote, the information: _A line can be split by substituting a `<newline>` into it. The application shall escape the `<newline>` in the replacement by preceding it by a `<backslash>`._ That requires a backslash-newline in the replacement text to embed the newline. The specification is probably mainly following ancient practice, but a bit more consistency would be nice (and GNU does that here).

Comment: Thanks for adding that. What consistency are you referring to? Supporting the string `'\n'` to represent a newline?

Comment: Yes; GNU `sed` is a bit more consistent (with itself) than the standard is. Having `\n` mean one thing on the LHS and a different thing on the RHS of the `s///` command is a little irritating.